# Qualities of a good relay (besides the obvious)

Tags: relays, bandwidth

I’m currently working on Roster, a tor project that aims to reward relay operators with good relays.

Besides the obvious requirements of a good relay (e.g. speed, geo-diversity, constant uptime), what qualities make a relay valuable to the Tor network and its users?

While this may not have a definite answer, I would appreciate all opinions on the matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll give it a shot:

- consistent fast speed being #1
- rewards based on total bandwidth available/consumed per period
- total consistent uptime
- Identity verification (at least online or via email)
- Community involvement (member of tor-relays, tor-talk, etc)
- Number of successful responses to complaints
- Hosting in a country that the Tor Network needs for geo-diversity
- bonus for multiple relays properly configured as a family
- rewards for a more open exit policy (e.g. *:*)
- running latest version of Tor or how fast the system upgrades
- running a server following best practices guide checklist (FDE, strong passwords, maintained patch levels, etc)
- Optional flags (e.g. HSDir, directory mirror)